# RuntimeError: shape '[512, 32]' is invalid for input of size 589824

Tags: deep-learning

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor

def squash(x):
    lengths2 = x.pow(2).sum(dim=2)
    lengths = lengths2.sqrt()
    x = x * (lengths2 / (1 + lengths2) / lengths).view(x.size(0), x.size(1))
    return x

class PrimaryCapsules(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, capsule_dimension):
        super(PrimaryCapsules, self).__init__()

        self.capsules = nn.ModuleList([
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=9, stride=2)
            for _ in range(capsule_dimension)
        ])

    def forward(self, x):
        u = [capsule(x) for capsule in self.capsules]
        u = torch.stack(u, dim=2)
        u = squash(u.squeeze(3))  # 수정된 부분
        return u

class DigitCapsules(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_capsules, in_channels, out_channels, num_routing):
        super(DigitCapsules, self).__init__()

        self.num_routing = num_routing

        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, num_capsules, in_channels, out_channels))

    def forward(self, u):
        batch_size = u.size(0)
        u = u[:, None, :, :, :]
        W = self.W[:, :, None, :, :]
        u_hat = torch.matmul(u, W)
        b_ij = torch.zeros(batch_size, u_hat.size(1), self.num_capsules, 1, 1)

        for iteration in range(self.num_routing):
            c_ij = F.softmax(b_ij, dim=2)
            s_j = (c_ij * u_hat).sum(dim=2, keepdim=True)
            v_j = squash(s_j)
            if iteration < self.num_routing - 1:
                a_ij = torch.matmul(u_hat.transpose(3, 4), v_j).squeeze(4).mean(dim=0, keepdim=True)
                b_ij = b_ij + a_ij

        return v_j.squeeze(2)

class CapsuleNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_routing):
        super(CapsuleNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 256, kernel_size=9, stride=1)
        self.primary_capsules = PrimaryCapsules(256, 32, 8)
        self.digit_capsules = DigitCapsules(10, 32 * 6 * 6, 16, num_routing)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.primary_capsules(x)
        x = self.digit_capsules(x)
        return x

training_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor(),
)

test_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=False,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor(),
)

batch_size = 512
train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size=batch_size)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=batch_size)

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
print(f"Using {device} device")

model = CapsuleNetwork(num_routing=3)
model.to(device)

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

def train(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    model.train()
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")

def test(dataloader, model, loss_fn):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    model.eval()
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
            pred = model(X)
            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, y).item()
            correct += (pred.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).sum().item()
    test_loss /= len(dataloader)
    correct /= size
    print(f"Test Error: \n Accuracy: {(100*correct):>0.1f}%, Avg loss: {test_loss:>8f} \n")

epochs = 5
for t in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
    train(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    test(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn)
print("Done!")
```

This is the code.

It makes

RuntimeError: shape '[512, 32]' is invalid for input of size 589824

this error.

I used capsule network deep-learning model

I understand that it's a dimension-related issue, but I'm not sure which part needs to be modified.

The data used is PyTorch's built-in dataset.
The input images are 2-dimensional grayscale images with height (H) and width (W), and the target labels are 1-dimensional tensors corresponding to the class labels of each image

please help